# How do I install a hard disk with Windows installed on it in a machine running Ubuntu 18.04.5?

Tags: grub2, hard-drive, windows

If I install the disk on the computer, will Grub on the primary partition/disk recognize this new disk and let me boot into Windows?

I should have mentioned in the question that this Windows install was created on the same computer. I just removed the disk to install larger ones and put Ubuntu on them. Now it turns out I need the Windows install and virtualbox cannot do what I need (use the NVidia RTX 2060 GPU).

Comment: No: GRUB is not smart; it's just a wee bootloader. After the HDD is mountable, boot into Ubuntu and run `update-grub` to add new options to GRUB.

Comment: After updating grub, Windows will probably throw a hissy fit being on different hardware.

Comment: If you have a future question it would be best to have the correct Ubuntu version number. 18.04 or 18.10 I doubt it was 18.

Comment: Please clarify your release(s).  Ubuntu uses *yy* releases only for specialist *snap* based releases for IoT appliances/devices or cloud based use (having done so since 2016). Main releases use *yy.mm* such as used by server & desktops releases.  (*Most of us are more familiar with Ubuntu 18.04 rather than the specialist  Ubuntu Core 18*)

Comment: Windows disk should work if it was created on the same computer it is being installed in. (or is a version of Windows-To-Go). It needs to be the same BIOS/UEFI mode as Ubuntu for Ubuntu's GRUB to boot it.

Comment: Title and question edited with the requested clarifications. Thanks.